# How to send extra data with SINManagedPush like "badge" and "sound" value?(iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, sinch

If I want to add some extra information with remote push before I send it out (like alert, badge, sound), I know I can set the "alert" content by [SINManagedPush setDisplayName:], but i can't find other way to set other value like "badge" and "sound" and other customs values, where should I add them with SINManagedPush?

I've finished managed push notification via SinchSDK 2.5.1 and it works well now, i can receive remote push after the app was killed, but I want to set "badge" and "sound" and custom values before it sent out. How can I add them?

PS: The app runs under iOS 7.1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that is not something you can do right now. Its in our backlog.